# MobaXterm right mouse button double click

Tags: copy-paste, right-mouse-button, mobaxterm

Recently I have updated/upgraded to version 10.2, free personal edition. I think right after the upgrade, the right-mouse-button behaviors changed.

I am a long time unix user, I always high light a selection in the term, and then double click the right-mouse-button to paste the selection in the place where the mouse cursor is.

But now, the **context menu** pops up when clicking the RMB regardless one-clicking or double clicking, and I have select the paste from the menu to paste the selection.

I don't see the reason why MobaXterm should change the behave in such a way that is annoying and inconvenient.

**How can I change it back to the way before like any other Xterm apps?**

Answer (score 27):

I found the setting:
Settings | Terminal

The check box `Paste using right-click` is default to unchecked.

check this box, and restart MobaXterm, the RMB double click will paste the selection without the context menu popping up.

Comment: Note that this is the global MobaXTerm Settings, it is NOT the Session Settings -> SSH -> Terminal which has a very similar looking Terminal settings page.  This note is for my future self when I have this question again when setting up a new machine...and google brings me back here.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Settings tab on the Top Panel

   [image: Top bar]
2. Select Settings->Configuration.

   [image: Configuration]
3. Under the Terminal Tab, inside the  "Terminal Features" Panel. Toggle "Paste using right-click" to ☑️ ( toggle : yes).

[image: MobaXterm Terminal Settings]